# EXT JS 5 - Is it possible to display combobox data in a tree view?

Tags: extjs, combobox, treeview

I am currently working on a project that will be written with EXT-JS 5 and I've been asked to minimize the number of "special purpose" controls required by the UI, and to rely on existing EXT-JS 5 components and simple customizations as much as possible.

There is a form going in the UI that would benefit from having a combobox with the selection area displayed like a single-select tree view. I have done some research and know that the EXT-JS 5 combobox does support customization but I am not familiar enough with the package (and don't have the time to become more familiar with it) to be able to tell whether it would be possible to customize it to use an EXT-JS 5 tree control.

I've done some searching on Google and these forums and have not found anything which specifically addresses this question and would appreciate advice, and possibly an example (if it is possible), from those more knowledgeable than I am.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible yes, You would likely need to implement a recursive function to iterate over the store and use each items tpl to change the layout. For example for 1st level items you could just output the text directly, for 2nd level you could append - to the start and so on. It might be worthwhile to search the Sencha Forums in the plugins section and see if anyone has implemented this already

Answer (score 0):

Extjs supprts treepicker as built-in. Check this https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile (gind treepicker) or this https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker